# Dynamic Laravel Queue Connection

Tags: php, laravel, queue, jobs

I have a 'proposal' table on my database, each proposal's row will generate a photo album (for all users) on certain time.

I set a queue to generate per photo album, so there's a thousand jobs in my jobs table at database.

to generate 1 photo album takes 4-10 seconds because there's an algorythm process.

I create 8 proposals, so the last photo album will take a long time to be generated, could someone have a solution for me?

Is there a way to create a multiple queue connection that run in the same time? lets say i have 5 proposal, so there's 5 queue connection, so each proposal has it's queue connection so the generate process will be done on time.

Thank you.

Comment: You have one queue *connection* (Redis/Beanstalkd/etc), but you can run as many queue *workers* as you want to run. However you are running your workers on your server, simply fire up 5 or so of them and they will all work in parallel. You could automatically scale this based on workload. However be aware that this approach will of course need more server power than just doing one at a time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation mentions the [Supervisor Configuration](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/queues#supervisor-configuration), and the example configuration has `numprocs=8`.

> In this example, the numprocs directive will instruct Supervisor to run 8 queue:work processes [...]

It sounds like you're running with `numprocs=1` which will only run one queue worker, thus only processing one job at a time.